# How to prevent default Escape key behaviour in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Currently when we have a model with hidden parts, a user can press the escape key and the listener function within the viewer has logic to show all hidden parts.  This is problematic for us - how can we prevent this behaviour?

Is there a way for me to remove this listener?

Answer (score 1):

This quite straightforward, just call this line somewhere:

```
viewer._hotkeyManager.popHotkeys( 'Autodesk.Escape' )
```

But be careful, this will remove all hotkeys registered with the name `Autodesk.Escape` and event triggers for `Autodesk.Viewing.ESCAPE_EVENT`.